# EF Table-Per-Type: Add new child to an existing parent

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm new with ASP.NET MVC Code First, I have implemented a table-per-type hierarchy that goes something like this:

```
public abstract class Request
{
    public int RequestId {gets;set;}
    public DateTime CreationDate {get;set;}
    public string CreatedBy {gets;set;}
    public bool Active {Get;set;}
}

public class RequestChildA : Request
{
    public string RequestChildAProp1 {get;set;}
    public string RequestChildAProp2 {get;set;}
    ...
}

public class RequestChildB : Request
{
    public string RequestChildBProp1 {get;set;}
    public string RequestChildBProp1 {get;set;}
    ...
}


Request table
+---------------+-------------------------+------------+--------+
|    RequestId  |       CreationDate      |  CreatedBy | Active | 
+---------------+-------------------------+------------+--------+
| 1             | 2019-08-19 09:40:39.817 | HydroFlask |    1   |
+---------------+-------------------------+------------+--------+

RequestChildA table
+---------------+-------------------------+---------------------+
|    RequestId  |   RequestChildAProp1    |  RequestChildAProp1 | 
+---------------+-------------------------+---------------------+
| 1             |         ValueA          |   ValueB            |
+---------------+-------------------------+---------------------+
```

ChildA and ChildB can share the same request. My question is how can I add a NEW ChildB to an existing Request that also has an existing ChildA.

I have tried the usual:

```
var childB = new childB { RequestChildBProp1 = "Value1", RequestChildBPro2 = "Value2" };
childB.RequestId = 1;
db.RequestChildB.Add(childB);
db.SaveChanges();
```

It is completed with no errors, but it creates a new Request. I need a new ChildB that is the same RequestId as the existing. Please help!

My design might be wrong, please bear with me. Thank you!

Comment: You don't want to inherit `Request` but include an instance of `Request` in each of the classes `ChildA` and `ChildB`. `Request` needs to be set to `virtual` in the Child classes.

Comment: Thank you Peter, so should I change the abstract class to a class only?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following, not tested:

```cs
public class Request
{
    public int RequestId {gets;set;}
    public DateTime CreationDate {get;set;}
    public string CreatedBy {gets;set;}
    public bool Active {Get;set;}
}

public class RequestChildA
{
    public string RequestChildAProp1 {get;set;}
    public string RequestChildAProp2 {get;set;}
    ...
    public virtual Request Request {get; set;}

}

public class RequestChildB
{
    public string RequestChildBProp1 {get;set;}
    public string RequestChildBProp1 {get;set;}
    ...
    public virtual Request Request {get; set;}
}
```

Comment: You probably want to remove the inheritance `: Request` from `RequestChildB` as well.

Comment: Thanks, the perils of copy and paste!

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need is creating your `RequestChildA` and `RequestChildB` like this:

```
public class RequestChildB
{
    public virtual Request Request {get;set;}

    public string RequestChildBProp1 {get;set;}
    public string RequestChildBProp1 {get;set;}
}
```

and insert data like this:

```
db.RequestChildB.Add(new RequestChildB
{
    Request = db.Request.Find(1),
    //...other properties
});

db.SaveChanges();
```